# How to navigate iron-selector items using arrow keys?

Tags: polymer

How to navigate iron-selector items using arrow keys?

```
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[icons]]">
            <iron-icon icon="[[item.name]]"/>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a combination of iron-a11y-keys and an array to keep track of what order your iron-selector items are in. iron-a11y-keys will allow to perform a javascript method when a specific key is pressed, then in that method you will need to determine what iron-selector item to transition to.